# Compiler Error Message: CS0009 - mscorlib.dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, mscorlib

When I try to run my web application, the following error occurs:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0009: Metadata file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' could not
>   be opened -- 'File is corrupt.'

It seems to me that the .NET framework 4 installation is corrupt, but I am using Windows 8.1, and I'm not sure how to repair this, as it is integrated into the Windows installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually copied the corrupted file from a different computer with the same Windows installation. It took some permission changing, but I managed to do it.